# How to represent object properties in given context?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decorator, trailblazer, representable

I am looking for a solution to my problem I have a relation => `Company` has_many `Councils`, through `CouncilCompany`.

And I would like to display Company in context of given Council, so if `CouncilCompany` has `name` property present display it over default `Company` `name`.

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: council_companies
#
#  id            :uuid             not null, primary key
#  name          :string
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: companies
#
#  id                   :uuid             not null, primary key
#  name                 :string          default(FALSE), not null
```

```
render json: Company::Representer::Show.new(@company).to_json(
  current_user: current_api_v1_user,
  council: @council
)
```

```
require 'representable/json'
module Company::Representer
  class Show < Representable::Decorator
    include Representable::JSON

    Company.columns_hash.keys.each do |column|
      property column.to_sym.as_json, render_nil: true
    end
  end
end
```

What would be the best way to do that?
Tried already to find solution here: https://trailblazer.to/2.1/docs/representable.html#representable-api

Comment: Don't know this gem but isn't this what you're looking for? https://trailblazer.to/2.0/gems/representable/3.0/api.html#execution-context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about defining a representer for `CouncilCompany` instead, as it belongs to `Company` ?

```rb
require 'representable/json'

module CouncilCompany::Representer
  class Show < Representable::Decorator
    include Representable::JSON

    property :name, default: -> { company.name }

    property :company do
      property :id
      property :name
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
render json: CouncilCompany::Representer::Show.new(@council_company).to_json(
  current_user: current_api_v1_user
)
```